# Vue - How to use lodash debounce

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lodash

I am using debounce from lodash which is imported in main.js

```js
import lodash from 'lodash'
Vue.prototype._ = lodash
```

And I am using like `this._.find(...)`, it's all working fine. But if i use debounce it is not working.

```html
<script>
   export default {
      methods: {
        delay: this._.debounce(function () {
         // Code
        }, 500),
      }
    }
</script>
```

It throws this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'debounce' of undefined`

What could be the right way to use the `this._.debounce(...)` ?

Comment: My guess is that `this` in your case does not refer to the vue prototype. Can you post the surrounding code?

Comment: judging by the 'delay' key, you are in an object which changes the context of 'this', post the entire code so we can know for sure.

Comment: Here, you will load the entire `lodash` library in your bundle, hence my solution which will only import the needed function.

Comment: net.uk.sweet, itay_alon i edited the post, the delay function is in methods section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```html
<script>
import { debounce } from 'lodash-es' // optimized es6-import package, similar to usual 'lodash'

export default {
  methods: {
    yourCoolFunction: debounce(function (event) { // event is the object parameter given to 'yourCoolFunction' if any
      // your tasty code
    }, 500),
  }
}
```

And don't forget to add this to the `nuxt.config.js` file too

```js
build: {
  transpile: ['lodash-es'],
}
```

---

For more details about what is a [`debounce`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce), you can check this article: https://redd.one/blog/debounce-vs-throttle

Comment: As i have already imported the lodash package in main.js, is there any way that i can use it from there?

Comment: Not sure about the issue here but you could also use `import debounce from 'lodash/debounce'`, the bundle size will be small too.

Answer (score 2):

Try this out. For me it worked as `_.debounce` as shown below:

```
    <script>
       export default {
          methods: {
             delay: _.debounce(function() {
               //code
             }, 700),
          }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: This is going to work only if we import lodash in that specific file right? Like `import _ from lodash`

Comment: I have imported it in the file where i am using debounce.